# Add data to sharepoint form programmatically on client

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a need to edit a Sharepoint form programmatically to update a text box on a form. The url of this form is `https://sharepointserver/NameOfList/DispForm.aspx?ID=141`. Using the sharepoint web services how can I add data to a field called "Description" on the form?

Comment: On a client? It means after the user has entered the form, on some point the data changes? Do you want to update the list field in AJAX way ?

Comment: As in on a client using a windows application, or console application without opening the web form in a browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - add a web service to your visual studio project to interact with SharePoint from windows/console app: [Accessing SharePoint Web-Services with Visual Studio 2008](http://olafd.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/accessing-sharepoint-web-services-with-visual-studio-2008/)

Then call WssLists.[UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
string strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" + 
    "<Field Name='ID'>141</Field>" +
    "<Field Name='Description'>My new Description</Field></Method>" +
    "</Method>"; 

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");

elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError","Continue");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion","1");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ViewName",
    "0d7fcacd-1d7c-45bc-bcfc-6d7f7d2eeb40");

elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;

XmlNode ndReturn = WssLists.UpdateListItems("List_Name", elBatch);
```

You can see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx) there are many web services available to interact with SharePoint.